# How to add a row based on last user event in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a dataframe with user events

```
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | event_name       | timestamp           |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | HomeAppear       | 2020-12-13 06:38:14 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | TariffsAppear    | 2020-12-13 06:40:13 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | CheckoutPayClick | 2020-12-13 06:50:12 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 2       | HomeAppear       | 2020-12-13 11:38:33 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 2       | TariffsAppear    | 2020-12-13 11:39:18 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
```

For each user after his last (by timestamp) event I want to add new row with 'End' event with the same timestamp as in previous event:

```
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | End              | 2020-12-13 06:50:12 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+
```

I have no idea how to do that. In SQL I would do that with LAG() or LEAD(). But what about pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for last row of `User_id`, change `event_name` to `End` and add to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting index (added safest sort `mergesort`):

```
#if necessary sorting
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'timestamp'], ignore_index=True)

df2 = df.drop_duplicates('user_id', keep='last').assign(event_name = 'End')

df = pd.concat([df, df2]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   user_id        event_name            timestamp
0        1        HomeAppear  2020-12-13 06:38:14
1        1     TariffsAppear  2020-12-13 06:40:13
2        1  CheckoutPayClick  2020-12-13 06:50:12
3        1               End  2020-12-13 06:50:12
4        2        HomeAppear  2020-12-13 11:38:33
5        2     TariffsAppear  2020-12-13 11:39:18
6        2               End  2020-12-13 11:39:18
```

Comment: Looks great! But how will pandas consider a row as last one based on timestamp value?

Comment: @РусланХ - Values of timestamps are sorted?

Comment: they are not sorted

Comment: @РусланХ - Ok, added solution to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'timestamp'])
df1=pd.DataFrame({'user_id':np.unique(df['user_id']),'event_name':'End','timestamp':np.NaN})
df=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=0).sort_values(by='user_id')
df['timestamp']=df['timestamp'].fillna(method='ffill')
```